# How to count each read & write operations programmatically

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Is there any tools to count firestore read & write operations?
Or how do you usually count each operations manually?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's no tool for you to keep a count on the operations in your Firestore database, you would need to manually keep track of them. I would rather recommend you to perform an estimate as depicted [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/billing-example#operations) if what you are trying to do is get an estimate of the billing you'll receive in the month.

If you have an issue with the number of reads you are currently performing, I would recommend you to take a look at [this](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-reduce-the-number-of-read-operations-in-cloud-firestore-9f9d6f5a271) article which may help you with that topic.